# Windows Store In App Purchase Issue “Value does not fall within the expected range”

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, desktop-application, desktop-app-converter

When performing an in-app purchase from a WPF Desktop Application using **StoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync()** from the namespace Windows.services.Store, we get a StorePurchaseResult with an ExtendedError message **"Value does not fall within the expected range."**

Our application is published and available for download from the Windows Store.

It was converted using the DesktopAppConverter tool. We set the manifest.appx according to the description in the Store (Identity Name, Publisher...).

We followed the instructions provided below for using in-app purchase in C# from the UI thread of a Windows desktop application that uses the Desktop Bridge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-purchases-of-apps-and-add-ons

In our app's code, we declare the IInitializeWithWindow interface :

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("3E68D4BD-7135-4D10-8018-9FB6D9F33FA1")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IInitializeWithWindow
{
  void Initialize(IntPtr hwnd);
}
```

Then, when our application is starting, we get the StoreContext (stored into the storeContext_ attribute), using the single-user way :

```
// Init the store context
storeContext_ = StoreContext.GetDefault();
IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)storeContext_;
initWindow.Initialize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
```

After this, we manage to retreive the StoreLicense (stored into the storeLicense_ attribute) and list the associated store products without any error

```
// Get the current user license
storeLicense_ = await storeContext_.GetAppLicenseAsync();
if (storeLicense_ == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while retrieving the license.", "StoreLicenseApp Error");
    return;
}

// Create a filtered list of the product AddOns I care about
string[] filterList = new string[] { "Durable" };

// Get list of Add Ons this app can sell, filtering for the types we know about
StoreProductQueryResult addOns = await storeContext_.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(filterList);
if (addOns.ExtendedError != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Impossible to retreive the list of the products on the store.\n" + addOns.ExtendedError.Message,
                               "Get Associated Store Products Error");
}
```

Once the store ids of the products are retreived from the store, we wait for the user to click on a purchase button that calls the callback below.

```
private async void PurchaseButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   StorePurchaseResult result = await storeContext_.RequestPurchaseAsync(selectedStoreId);
   
   // Capture the error message for the operation, if any.
   string extendedError = string.Empty;
   if (result.ExtendedError != null)
   {
                   extendedError = result.ExtendedError.Message;
   }
               
               [...]
}
```

`RequestPurchaseAsync()` return an error instead of showing the Metro interface for purchasing the product.
Here is the extended error returned :

> Message = "Value does not fall within the expected range."
>
> HResult = -2147024809

Any clue of how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Just according to this error message, we cannot look up the cause for your failing request. Can you provide your provide product IDs (for the parent app and the IAP product) if possible?

Comment: Hi Mattew, here is the parent app one 9NFMR9KZRHTV and the IAP is 9PHL59JKBHNC

Comment: Could you please run **WSCOLLECT** and provide store logs here?

Comment: Does it provide you enough informations ?

Comment: @ZhendongWu-MSFT I am also facing this issue - I would like to know if there was any resolution. Our app ID is 9PGBZ1L0KRS8 and we tried two dev-managed consumables, with IDs of 9N0S0GZNCX53 and 9N3SJVF4HM66. Here is a paste of the errors collected by WSCOLLECT: https://pastebin.com/RYLjsS37

Comment: We've also tested and received the same result with a durable IAP. By the way, @ZhendongWu-MSFT, the requested WSCOLLECT log from jarne was posted as an answer in case you missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequestPurchaseAsync()` called in our `PurchaseButton_Clicked()` function was returning an error because we was initializing the store context in another function when the application was starting.

We solved the issue by placing the store context initializing instructions in the `PurchaseButton_Clicked()` as follow :

```
public async void PurchaseSelectedProduct(ProductModel product){
    if (product == null){
        MessageBox.Show("Product not valid", "PurchaseInApp Error");
        return;
    }

    // Init store context for purchase
    IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)storeContext_;
    initWindow.Initialize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);

    // Buy through in app purchase sdk
    StorePurchaseResult result = null;
    try { result = await product.StoreProduct.RequestPurchaseAsync(); }
}
```